# Deploying a Spring app as ear to Glassfish v3 - Ambiguous DeploymentException "Module type not recognised"

Tags: spring, maven-2, jakarta-ee, glassfish, ear

I am trying to deploy an .ear to Glassfish v3. The .ear is a "Spring" application made up of two modules:

1. `domain.jar` (entities, persistence)
2. `service.jar` (business logic with spring bean config).

I'm creating the .ear with Maven ear plugin and the resultant dir structure of the .ear is as follows:

- `/APP-INF/lib/domain.jar;service.jar`
- `/META-INF/application.xml`

I've copied the Spring dist to /glassfish/lib so it is available to all domains on the app server.

UPDATE:

It turns out that commenting out `<includeInApplicationXml>true</includeInApplicationXml>` from the ear `pom.xml` will make it deploy. But then my `domain.jar` is not deployed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand the structure of your EAR. Why are you packaging `domain.jar`  and `service.jar` (this one contains EJBs right?) as utility JAR under `APP-INF/lib`? This doesn't look correct to me and I'd expect the following structure instead:

```
myear
|-- META-INF
|   `-- application.xml
|-- domain.jar
`-- service.jar
```

Am I missing something about your app?

---

> No, maybe I'm misunderstanding the structure of an ear... I've struggled to find any good articles explaining it - I don't think it helps I'm trying to learn to use Maven too.

The [Packaging Applications](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaby.html) section of the Java EE tutorials is pretty decent.

> I'm quite happy making a multi-module project, but I'm struggling to package it up successfully.

[Because I always forget how to use maven-ear-plugin](http://agoncal.wordpress.com/2009/10/23/because-i-always-forget-how-to-use-maven-ear-plugin/) could help... if you really need an EAR.

Comment: No, maybe I'm misunderstanding the structure of an ear...I've struggled to find any good articles explaining it - I don't think it helps I'm trying to learn to use Maven too. I'm quite happy making a multi-module project, but I'm struggling to package it up successfully.

Comment: Thanks Pascal - I'll take a read. I was looking at demoing different flavours of web services from the same project. A persistence module (JPA) with some business logic over the top (EJB3 and Spring), and a suite of web apps (SOAP and rest) exposing the business logic. Unfortunately I believe it would be better to separate them into separate projects to avoid conflicts.

Comment: Sorted it all - cheers for pointing me in the right direction!